# What is this techinique called?

Tags: javascript

I come from C#. A small example with C# syntax:

```
// using System.Linq;

int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
int result = array.SingleOrDefault(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

I want to `convert` that syntax to javascript syntax:

```js
Array.prototype.singleOrDefault = function (tsource) {
 var $self = this
 if ($self.length) {
   for (let i = 0; i < $self.length; i++) {
     if (tsource($self[i])) {
       return $self[i]
      }
    }
    return null
  }
};

var test = function () {
  var array = [1, 2, 3, 5];
  var result = array.singleOrDefault(x => x % 2 === 0)
  if (result !== null) {
   alert(result)
  }  
};
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Click me</button>
```

In C#: `.SingleOrDefault(TSource)` is called `Linq method` which referenced from `System.Linq` namespace.

So, my question is: what is `.singleOrDefault(x => x % 2 === 0)` called in this case (in javascript)?

Comment: lambda expression? anonymous function?

Comment: its a monkey patched function.

Comment: Are you asking what functions like `.singleOrDefault()` are called, or what the `x => x % 2 === 0` part is called, or...? (By the way, your function seems to do basically the same thing as the standard array [`.find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).)

Comment: Calling them Linq methods helps to clarify where they come from, and that they are part of a set of external methods you can use.  Since you are writing this yourself you might just call it a prototype extension method or something.  That wouldn't really help clarify it to others because you wrote it yoursef.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes. It's same to `.find()`. But you cannot use lambda expression with `.find()`. So, it's not same.

Comment: What do *you* mean by "lambda expression"? JavaScript allows anonymous function expressions, so both `someArray.find(x => x % 2 === 0)` and `someArray.find(function(x) { return x%2===0 })` are perfectly valid.

Comment: @nnnnnn I just try again. Im sorry. The doc doesn't mention about it.

Comment: In JS you can use an anonymous function anywhere that a function reference is expected. So functions like `.find()`, `.map()`, `.singleOrDefault()`, etc., that expect a function as an argument can all be called either with an anonymous function as in your example, or with a reference to a function defined elsewhere as in `arr.singleOrDefault(someFunc)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Many thanks! I want to expand something. Case: `var obj = { prop1: value1, prop2: value2 }; var result = obj.find(x.prop1 == value1);` So, `.find()` hasn't supported yet. I need to rewrite it

Comment: `obj.find()` doesn't make sense: what would `result` be in that example? If you had an array of such objects you could say `arr.find(x => x.prop1 == value1)` to get the first object in the array that has a `prop1` property equal to `value1`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I mean: I can use `.SingleOrDefault()` for both an object and an array in C#. So, why cannot `.find()` do that too? That's the reason I want to handle the function `.singleOrDefault()` in javascript.

Comment: `.find()` can't do that because it doesn't make sense to use it on an object. The JS `.singleOrDefault()` shown in the question only works on arrays (or array-like objects if invoked via `.call()` or `.apply()`). The C# Linq `singleOrDefault()` works on enumerable collections, i.e., on lists of things, not on single objects. Having said all that, you certainly can write a function in JS that can work on objects *and* arrays where it makes sense to do so (but you'd have to extend `Object.prototype`, not `Array.prototype`, noting that in general extending built-in objects is frowned upon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a JS library to call the same function: https://linqjs.codeplex.com/

It contains around 90 mehtods

This is an example related to your method.

```
var jsonArray = [
{ "user": { "id": 100, "screen_name": "d_linq" }, "text": "to objects" },
{ "user": { "id": 130, "screen_name": "c_bill" }, "text": "g" },
{ "user": { "id": 155, "screen_name": "b_mskk" }, "text": "kabushiki kaisha" },
{ "user": { "id": 301, "screen_name": "a_xbox" }, "text": "halo reach" }
]
// ["b_mskk:kabushiki kaisha", "c_bill:g", "d_linq:to objects"]
var queryResult = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
.Where(function (x) { return x.user.id < 200 })
.OrderBy(function (x) { return x.user.screen_name })
.Select(function (x) { return x.user.screen_name + ':' + x.text })
.ToArray();
// shortcut! string lambda selector
var queryResult2 = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
.Where("$.user.id < 200")
.OrderBy("$.user.screen_name")
.Select("$.user.screen_name + ':' + $.text")
.ToArray();
```

Comment: Although you don't answer my question, I like `linqjs`. It's friendly. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to mark my answer as the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a ternary operand would be the substitute in JS

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: I don't understand how you reached that conclusion. You can't replace that function with a ternary **operator**.

Comment: Operand is the element that the operator acts upon - which is what I am referring to. Been doing this a long time man, I know my terminology - but thanks. Here, maybe you need a refresher: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

His function is testing values - with the intent of determining if the value is "single" or "default". The return on that (true or false) using a ternary function is the closest thing I can think of in JS that does not require a bunch of "if" conditionals.

Comment: OK, sorry about the terminology, I still don't understand how what you're saying relates to what the OP is doing. The OP already has a JS expression that returns true or false, so the closest thing in JS to what OP is doing is what they're *already* doing.. (P.S. Regarding knowing your terminology, I *did* see your comment before you replaced "logic" with "element"; we all make mistakes...)

Comment: @Korgrue It's better to understand if you rewrite my function with ternary operator in your answer.

Comment: I think I misunderstood OPs original question - I thought he was referring to the functionality of the code, as in what is this type of functionality called. I viewed what OP was trying to do was compare values and get a return based on the inputs - which to me would be expressed as a ternary. Ignore my answer - its off course.